# ASP.NET: GridView and DetailsView, Do I have to have separate connections to same database?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I have a GV and a DV that extract data from the same database. The link between these controls is when a record in the GV is selected, the DV displays more details about that record.

Do I need separate connections? Obviously, I haven't achieved this goal and am working on it. Thanks.

CLARIFICATION so as not to waste your time:

I am asking about connection, not datasource. The reason that I am not sure the same connection can be used is that with GV,  the connection doesn't have any parameter. Whereas with the DV, it needs the record ID passed to it. Or am I wrong?

Here's the link to code on the net that makes me wonder:
http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/util/srcview.aspx?path=~/aspnet/samples/data/GridViewMasterDetails.src

I am a novice so am still confused with the terminology. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: You will need an ID passed. You can search through the datasource for the object to fill the DV. You will get the ID from the selected row of the GV and you can use it to search the DataTable for the row needed to fill the DV. You can use the Select() function on the DataTable to fulfill this need.

Comment: Thanks, @jmein, I am adding some code that I saw on the net which makes me wondering. Please see my edited question.

Comment: You can use 2 datasources if you want or you can search upon the first datasource using the ID given.

Comment: Thanks so much @jmein. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can use the same datasource. (Such as an ObjectDataSource or SQLDataSource)

Comment: and other folks: to clarify, I am not asking about DATASOURCE. I am asking about CONNECTION.

Comment: @user776676 You can use the same connection. If you are using an actual SQLConnection object you can still use the same connection to bind both. However, I recommend using the DataSource objects to make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same data source, i.e. a DataTable. But when the Gridview row is selected you will need to find the index of the selected row and then find the DataRow from the DataTable and rebind your DetailView to that DataRow. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using Visual Studio databinding, and I would say that same Connection(DataSource) object can be used (if that is the way it goes), but I would rather suggest you avoid this design time Visual Studio programming, although it is simple and fast